# AcroFields not copied using PDFWriter

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am creating a function to add pages at the end of an existing PDF document using ITextSharp. The PDF contains acrofields that I populate before adding new pages.

When I execute it without adding the new pages, the PDF is generated as expected, all fields populated.
but when I execute and call my function to add pages, the PDF is generated with new pages, but all fields are now blank...

Here is my code :

```
// The first PdfReader in the list is my main pdf, with all fields.
private void AddPages(List<PdfReader> pdfs)
{
 byte[] all;

 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
  Document doc = new Document();

  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

  doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
  doc.Open();
  PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
  PdfImportedPage page;

  foreach (PdfReader p in pdfs)
  {
    int pages = p.NumberOfPages;

    // loop over document pages
    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
    {
      doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
      doc.NewPage();
      page = writer.GetImportedPage(p, i);
      cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  doc.Close();
  all = ms.GetBuffer();
  ms.Flush();
  ms.Dispose();
}

// I tried to add this code, but doesn't change anything.
AcroFields fields = Output.AcroFields;

// Output is my PdfStamper I returned, my final PDF
Output = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(all), outStream);

foreach (var field in fields.Fields)
Output.AcroFields.Fields.Add(field);
```

}

Any idea why my fields are blanked out and how to solve it ?

Thanks a lot

---

**EDIT:**

According to comments, here is my new function :

```
byte[] all;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  Document doc = new Document();
  PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, ms);

  doc.Open();
  foreach (PdfReader pdf in pdfs)
      copy.AddDocument(pdf);

  doc.Close();

  all = ms.ToArray();
}

Output = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(all), outStream);
```

But I still have the same issue. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: `PdfWriter.GetImportedPage` only imports page *content*, not add-ons like annotations (e.g. form field widgets). For copying complete pages, please use `PdfCopy`.

Comment: The behavior you experience is expected and described in the documentation. See [Chapter 6 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) or [How to merge documents correctly?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly) or many other examples and Q&As on the [official iText developers site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/). You fill a form using `PdfStamper`, why don't you just [insert an extra page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-cover-page-existing-pdf-document)?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited my code but I still get the same issue (pages added but fields are blanked out). I've edited my question with the new code

Comment: EDIT : After checking deeper, it appears that fields are populated but the content is visible only when I click on the field !

Answer (score 0):

If it may help anyone, here is my code that now works :

```
byte[] all;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  Document doc = new Document();
  PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, ms);
  copy.SetMergeFields();

  doc.Open();
  foreach (PdfReader pdf in pdfs)
       copy.AddDocument(pdf);

  doc.Close();

  all = ms.ToArray();
}

Output = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(all), outStream);
Output.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

Thanks to @Bruno Lowagie and @mkl !